# Jquery - display data in html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[SOLVED] 
How to display data in html tag from Jquery code?

I loop through the json response from server and need to write these elements to some tag in html.

**What I have:** I receive response from server well. Looping through it also OK. 
 
**The problem:** The elements are actually appended, which I can see because the page size is increased immensely after completing my Jquery function. **BUT** with having the size of page increased I don't see any text on it I expect to.
I suppose it's because the parent element of the tag I'm appending to is given *(display:none)* by default. But I actually initiate its appearing by *$("#allowed").show();*. 
Still it's not working.

I would appreciate any help immensely. Thanks in advance!

***My html extract:***

```
   <section id="allowed" style="display:none;">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        <div id="nearest_banks">
            <form action="/nearest_banks/" method="get" id="send_radius">
              Курс ближайших банков на сегодня в радиусе
              <input type="text" name="radius" id="radius" size="5" value={{radius}} >
              <input type="submit" class="button" value="V">
               метров
            </form>
            <div id="places"> </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

***My Javascript extract:***

```
$("#yes").click(function() {
        $("#ask_user").hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: '/nearest_banks/radius',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#allowed").show();
                var str = "";
                $("#places").empty();
                $.each(data.places, function(index, element) {
                    str += '<p>' + '<span class="name">' + element.name + '</span>' +
                            '<span class="location">' + element.location + '</span>' +
                            '</p>'
                });
                $('#places').append(str);
            }});
    });
```

**EDIT:**
I found the solution. The main problem was indeed in css. Still some answers were up to the point concerning the performance improvement and correct syntax, so I edited the code according to them. 
Thus the code above is edited and is working fast enough. Hope this question will help someone someday.

Comment: `$('#places').append('<p class="location">' + element + '</p>');` and use class="location" instead of id.

Comment: Beware using `append()` in a loop isn't a great idea as it is requesting the DOM on each iteration. You'd have better to concatenate a string inside loop and append it only once after loop completes

Comment: @dfsq, I've made the changes but unfortunately the same problem

Comment: @A. Wolff, could you please give some short example how to concatenate them and append only after loop finishes. It's my first experience with JS so some things are not so clear about it's syntax

Comment: .. ***the page size is increased immensely after completing my Jquery function*** .. I am curious; how're you checking the page size?

Comment: well, by the scrollbar

Comment: e.g: `var str = "";
$.each(data.location, function (index, element) {
    str += '<p class="location">' + element + '</p>';
});
$('#places').append(str);`  That's said IDs ***must*** be unique on document context, that's why i used a class instead

Comment: That's odd! Do you by any chance have the CSS rule: `visibility:hidden` anywhere in your markup or CSS file?

Comment: @A. Wolff, thanks! that's was useful tip about sending to tag afterwards

Comment: @PeterKA, no i don't have _visibility:hidden_

Answer (score 0):

Find out why your css is hiding the html. Now JS:

Example of json response:

```
var data.location= [ 
     {"ID": 139004, "Name": "Madison Square Garden", "Adress": "4 Pennsylvania Plaza, New York, NY 10001, United States"}, 
     {"ID": 1390040, "Name": "Eiffel Tower", "Adress": "Champ de Mars, 5 Avenue Anatole France, 
    75007 Paris, France"}, 
     {"ID": 1390059, "Name": "Big Ben", "Adress" : "London SW1A 0AA, United Kingdom"}
    ];
```

Fix: **p id='location_" + index + "'** to have unique id's in html or remove id atribute

Using element parameter:

```
success: function (data) {
            $("#allowed").show();
            $.each(data.location, function(index, element) {
                $('#places').append("<p id='location_" + index + "'> ID: " + element.ID+ " Name: " + element.Name +"</p>");
            });            
            console.log(data);
        }});​
```

Using index parameter

```
success: function (data) {
            $("#allowed").show();
            $.each(data.location, function(index) {
                $('#places').append("<p id='location_" + index + "'> ID: " + data[index].ID+ " Name: " + data[index].Name +"</p>");
            });            
            console.log(data);
        }});​
```

Appending row json:

```
success: function (data) {
            $("#allowed").show();
            $.each(data.location, function(index, element) {
                $('#places').append("<p id='location_" + index + "'> " + JSON.stringify(element) + "</p>");
            });            
            console.log(data);
        }});​
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. It helped me with syntax although in terms of performance it's not that perfect as It's really calls the DOM on each iteration. So I followed the tip of A. Wolff and made the function write to html only once. Above in my question is fully working code now